# share session variables to subdomains in a online shop website

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-cookies, subdomain

I got a online-shop as www.mysite.com and have aditional 9 subdomains for each category of the products i was trying to pass the session variables from a domain to another with `ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.mysite.com' );`
It works for me , but for most of the users doesn't i just whant to show them how many product's they have in the shoping cart and how much they have to pay.
Is there another function to share the sessions to subdomains without this or `ini_set('session.cookie_domain', substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],"."),100));`
I was searching alot for the right answer.
the line of the code is on first line in index.php to be loaded when a person enters the site and then `session_start();`

Comment: You are you looking for sharing the cookie between multiple subdomains, right? If so, please do an exemplary list (use `example.com` as base, that's more accepted than `mysite.com`). Is `mysite.com`/`example.com` (without any further sld in front, not even `www`) hosting the shopping cart?

Comment: I did find my answer that ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.mysite.com') had to be in all root files to work :) thx for response anyway

Comment: well, be so kind a leave a link to the answer you've found so that it is clear to what you related to in your question.